# Using Selenium to send text to tinymce control not working for IE9

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, tinymce

I have an extension method to send text to a tinymce control for a series of test cases for an web application that has numerous tinymce controls throughout.  my method works in FireFox and Chrome but not in IE the other browser we support.  Any help getting this to work in IE would be greatly appreciated - below is my method code:

```
public static void SendTextToMCE(this IWebDriver driver, string mceControl, string message)
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(mceControl);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("tinymce")).SendKeys(message);
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.CurrentWindowHandle);
    }
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors - just no text (carried in message variable) in the control.  I have another method which follows the same pattern but executes .clear() method that works fine in IE but when I try to send text to the control, nothing - the control text box stays empty.  I noticed that the cursor seems to be in another text box on the page when it fails so I'm thinking a focus issue but I thought the driver.SwitchTo should take care of that and like I said in the original - this works just fine in Chrome and FireFox (i.e. text is populated to the control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *one* TinyMCE element in your page then you can send your text via TinyMCE's scripts:

```
var obj = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('" + text + "');");
```

Answer (score 0):

I try following code in C# & it's fine for me.

```
public void main ()
{
  driver.SwitchTo().Frame("description-editor_ifr");
  IWebElement element = _WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body"));
  element.Clear();
  element.SendKeys("Hello");

  //Go back to main frame
  driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
}
```